# ngFor First and Last Instance of a Class Do This

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-ng-class

I am using Angular 4+.  Please note: first and last needs to be based on the class instance, not the element.  So a let first = first in the ngFor will not work.  I currently imported jQuery to handle this but would like to see if there is a way not to use jQ.

In the component ts file:

```
items: any = [{number: 0, text: 'blah blah'},{number: 0, text: 'blah blah'},{number: 1, text: 'blah blah'},{number: 1, text: 'blah blah'},{number: 1, text: 'blah blah'}, etc...
```

In the HTML file:

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let item of items [ngClass]="'item-class-' + item.number">
  <ion-col>{{item.text}}</ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Now what I want to do is grab the first instance of a class and last - once I have it I want to style it or add a class to the row.  For example in jQuery I would have done this:

```
$( 'ion-row.item-class-0' ).first().css( 'background-color', 'red' );
$( 'ion-row.item-class-1' ).first().css( 'background-color', 'red' );
```

Answer (score 0):

updated answer :

**template :**

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let item of items" [ngClass]="'item-class-' + item.number">
    <ion-col>{{item.text}}</ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({...})
export class HomePage {

    items: any = [{
        number: 0,
        text: 'blah blah'
    }, {
        number: 0,
        text: 'blah blah'
    }, {
        number: 1,
        text: 'blah blah'
    }, {
        number: 1,
        text: 'blah blah'
    }, {
        number: 1,
        text: 'blah blah'
    }];

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        $( 'ion-row.item-class-0').first().css( 'background-color', 'red' );
        $( 'ion-row.item-class-1').last().css( 'background-color', 'red' );
    }
}
```

[image]

it will be working for me try this :

Comment: first and last need to be based on the class instance, not the element.

Comment: in this jquery method where it will be declared ? ngOnit or constructor ??

Comment: In Class ngAfterViewInit()

Comment: @RooksStrife i just updated answer can check and try like this ? and if it's not working in your project check your jquery if it's installed correctly or working

Comment: thanks, I have this.  I am trying to do it without using jQuery- in an Angular way if possible.  If not I'll stick with jQ.